# Switch from tabs to collapse for responsive

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

The goal is to switch from tabs to an accordion style collapse when the site is less than 676px wide. We are using Bootstrap.

We'll hide ul.nav-tabs and a.accordtion-toggle respectively with css. The tabs work here, but the a.accordion-toggle aren't working. Any ideas?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#panel1" data-toggle="tab">Panel 1</a></li>    
  <li class="active"><a href="#panel2" data-toggle="tab">Panel 2</a></li> 
</ul>

<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panel>Panel 1</a>
  <div class="tab-pane collapse" id="panel1">
 Panel 1 Content
  </div>
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pane2>Panel 2</a>
  <div class="tab-pane collapse" id="panel2">
 Panel 2 Content
  </div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <  767) {
        $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }

        $(".collapse").collapse();
     }              
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The pasted code has missing quote on attributes and the JS doesn't do anything. One of the `.accordion-toggle[data-target]` is also incomplete.

Comment: Have you thought about using the collapse plugin in the `.nav-tabs` instead of the tab plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a bit on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/FQa3G/) but **it seems complicated to make both plugins work together**.

It might be better opting for one of the plugin, using only the classes and JS of this plugin, and then implement your own triggers to complete the default behavior.

---

I think the accordion behavior of the collapse plugin needs the `.accordion-group > .collapse.in` structure to work properly - if you don't use your own JS.

Answer (score 11):

In my case just copying tabs content into hidden accordion worked well.

Here is the source I extracted to small plugin - [Bootstrap Tab Collapse](https://github.com/okendoken/bootstrap-tabcollapse)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up nesting the tab triggers inside one div with the tabbed content (instead of a list above) and using css to position them like tabs for the full screen view. Not ideal but works as long as the data-toggle and data-target are in place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but you could use  window.onresize = function() {} and check for the width of your main container. When it is less than some width you could replace the content using js.

Comment: this is against the design of bootstrap.

Col sizes and @media are the much preferred in the documentation as they play nicer with more browsers.