# Semantic ui accordion dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I am dealing with a strange problem.
I want to use a tabular menu inside the accordion.

Now the problem is that somehow the html gets scrambled inside the accordion.

I have made a fiddle to demonstrate this problem:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9epryur/5/)

is just do a standard:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var accordion = $('.ui.accordion');
  $(accordion).accordion();

  $('.tabular.menu .item').tab();
})
```

The problem occurs when you toggle the first tab or open any other tab.
On first initialization there is nothing wrong en everything works fine.

I hope anyone can help me out with this

Comment: Hi, I noticed that switching to tab 3 under any of the accordion dropdowns will change it to tab 3 under every single one. Fix:  change the `.tab()` bit to `$('.tabular.menu .item').each(function(){ $(this).tab(); });`

Comment: Hey I'm suspicious that this might have something to do with how the accordion works... Maybe it shows all its children elements and in turn screws up the tabs. Maybe this isn't doable as expected?

Comment: Hello that is exactly what i think, but what is so special at this accordion why this happens? It only has to toggle the visibitlity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904109/switch-from-tabs-to-collapse-for-responsive How funny, I was trying to help you last night and now I've got a similar problem to fix at work today... Check out this question, maybe it's related?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys, really appreciate it!

The fix is given on the [github repo](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5421)

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion({
  animateChildren: false
})
```